# Setting the domain in an ACL on a Google Calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-calendar-api, acl

I'm trying to set an acl on a google calendar so that I can conduct a free/busy read on the calendar from my site. I'm doing this:

```
 var request = gapi.client.calendar.acl.insert({"calendarId":calendar,"role":"freeBusyReader","scope":{"type":"domain","value":"mydomain.org"}});
```

And when I list the acls after running this, I can see that it successfully added the acl. However, when I conduct the free/busy request later on from mydomain.org, the calendar reports an error of "notFound". However, if I set the type to "default" in the ACL insert statement, then I can conduct the free/busy request and it returns the data I want. But I don't want to set the calendar's free/busy access to be public, which is what "default" does, I just want only my site to have the access. Am I not understanding what the domain means, or do I need to do something else?

**EDIT:** Here is the scenario. I am trying to create a website for a sports team, and I want team members to authorize my website to access their calendars so that as a coach, I can query all team members calendars at once and see who will miss practice scheduled at a given time. I have a page where each user chooses and authorizes my site to have access to their personal calendars using oauth, however, a free/busy API query doesn't work unless the member's calendar is set to share the free/busy data, via an ACL. I want to set the ACL so that it only grants my website free/busy access, not global free/busy access, because that seems a little invasive to me.

Comment: Can you explain your scenario? you are trying to give your domain access to free/busy information to your personal calendar? I tried this scenario and got same error as you are getting. However if I try with default, still I got the same error. Try your request here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/acl/insert and let me know the result

Comment: @SGC, See my edit above.

Comment: Unless user shares their calendar(free/busy) information to your application through acl or from UI , your application cannot access it.